# How can one calculate area from a shapefile?

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have a shapefile

```
> shpfile
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 60.85388, 105.0447, 15.95789, 39.31873  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 3
names       :                            NAME,    Shape_area,     Shape_len 
value       : The Hindu Kush-Himalayan Region, 398.729418943, 262.252297545
```

Note that the shape area is mentioned, however how can the area can calculated in R?

Comment: take  a look at the sf-package... `sf::st_area()` might suit your needs..

Comment: Find the area of a polygon using its vertices?  There is a short little write up on it here in part 3 of this [wikihow article](https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Polygon).